# c# extract all files but not these which end with word "Empty"

Tags: c#, .net

to get all the files, which contains `CustsExport`in its name, in a folder I do this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(xmlFolder, "*CustsExport*.xml"))
```

but there is a case where I don't want to extract the file that its name ends with `Empty` like this:

```
Erb3PCustsExport-303_20080319_063109_000_Empty
```

Could you help me please?

Many thanks

Comment: how about combining 'if' with string.endswith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LINQ-power and `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(xmlFolder, "*CustsExport*.xml")
    .Where(fn => !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).EndsWith("Empty")))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, you always help me, and I appreciate your efforts. Could you check my new question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045341/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-null-value-exception