# c# LINQ to XML null value exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my code:

```
List<Customer> customersList =
                (
                    from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                    select new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerID = (int)e.Element("custid"),
                        FirstName = (string)e.Element("fname"),
                        LastName = (string)e.Element("lname"),
                        ShowsNumber = (int)e.Element("count_noshow"),
                        VisitNumber = (int)e.Element("count_resos"),
                        Cancellation = (int)e.Element("count_cancel"),
                    }).ToList();
```

I got `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"}` exception on the `customerList = (....)` part of the code,

I can see the XML, it has a lot of `cust` nodes under the `root` node.

could you help me please?

Many thanks
Best regards,

#### Update1

The XML:

```
<root source="ERB" versionmajor="5" versionminor="0" filetype="3PCustomer">
    <cust rid="303" custid="5" lname="Test" fname="Test" emailoptin="1" mailoptin="1" datecreated="2006-01-12T15:37:54.450" count_resos="2" count_noshow="0" count_cancel="0">
        <phone phonenumber="408.123.4567" countrycodeid="1" phonetype="Home"/>
        <custcode ccode="Vegetarian"/>
    </cust>
    <cust rid="303" custid="6" lname="John" fname="Doe" email="johnD@ot.com" emailoptin="0" mailoptin="1" cnotes="Half caf double de-caf, with a twist..." datecreated="2006-01-12T17:09:57.013" count_resos="2" count_noshow="0" count_cancel="0">
        <phone phonenumber="456.456.4565" countrycodeid="1" phonetype="Home"/>
        <custcode ccode="Guest Share"/>
    </cust>
    <cust rid="303" custid="7" webcustid="1654438" lname="doe" fname="john" emailoptin="1" mailoptin="1" datecreated="2006-01-13T11:04:25.653" count_resos="1" count_noshow="0" count_cancel="0">
        <phone phonenumber="123.456.7890" countrycodeid="1" phonetype="Home"/>
    </cust>
    <!-- (...) -->
</root>
```

Comment: Can you show the XML? We can't help you without it. It might be a namespace issue.

Comment: how about pasting a small snippet of the XML file that you are reading from so that we can gain a visual of what you are seeing

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Okay,I will upload it.

Comment: One propable cause of the error you are getting is that one of the 'int' child elements of cust is empty

Comment: @DJKRAZE I updated the question with the xml

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos the value in the XML is already validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `Element()`, but custid, fname, etc.are not elements rather they are `attributes`.

Update it like this:-

```
List<Customer> customersList =
                (
                    from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                    select new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                        FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                        LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                        ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                        VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                        Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: exactly. It works !! :) +1 I will accept your answer when the system allows